# How do I just fetch the primary key(s) alone from a table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity public class GroupUser { Group g; User u; }. How do I fetch just the primary key(s) of all users. (i.e. List of u.getId() for a query where you fetch all users which belong to a group). I don't want to fetch the entire row, since it seems to take more time right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need the query it's pretty simple

`select u.Id from User u` and put it in a Collection of long

Answer (score 2):

In an HQL query, you can use the property `id` to refer to an entity's primary key (assuming that it doesn't define a non-pkey property called "id", of course).  Thus you could constrain an HQL query with a select clause as so:

```
select u.id
from Groups g inner join Users u
```

where the inner join excludes any users that don't belong to a group.  Of course you could apply any standard constraints to this query as well.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use hql.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html